# Looping code for range of cells instead of validating one cell at a time

Tags: vba, excel

I have added the snapshot. In this u can see the code is working for C4 cell for mobile number validation. So, I want it to work for C4-C16 and show result is A26/B26. If condition fails anywhere between C4-C16, B26 should be 'Number not OK.

[image: ter]

This code is working for one one cell as assigned but I would like to change it to validate range of cells.

In this code the first condition checks for specific header in C3 cell which is fine but after that the code is checking for the number is starting from '44' in cell C4 and its length.

So, I want to update this part so that code checks cell C4 to C16 and look if the length is between 10 and 13 and starts with '44' and if any cell is missing this condition then B27 should show message 'The subscriber number is not OK.

```
Sub Validate13()
Dim mymsg As String
Dim celltext As String
Dim celltext1 As String
celltext = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Text
celltext1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Text
celltext2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Text

If InStr(1, celltext1, "mz_013_reg-life_") = 1 Then
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The Header is OK."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The header is not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If InStr(1, celltext, "44") = 1 Then
 Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number starts with 44 and is OK."
 Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number is not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Len(celltext) > 10 And Len(celltext) < 13 Then
 Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number length is " & Len(celltext) & " and is OK ."
 Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number Length not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

If Len(celltext2) > 13 And Len(celltext2) < 15 Then
 Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestamp length is " & Len(celltext2) & " and is OK ."
 Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestanmp not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: one print screen, or file example, of your sheet will be easier to understand what you want

Comment: added screenshot. Please help!

Comment: You could do a For Each Loop around your code, and have a boolean to check if any numbers aren't ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, let me know:

```
Sub Validate13()
Dim mymsg As String
Dim celltext1 As String
Dim condition1 As Boolean
Dim condition2 As Boolean

celltext1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Text
celltext2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Text



condition1 = False
i = 4
Do

    If InStr(1, Range("C" & i).Text, "44") = 1 Then
        condition1 = True

            If condition1 = True And i = 16 Then
                 Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number starts with 44 and is OK."
                Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If

    Else
        Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number is not OK. Please check."
        Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbYellow
        condition1 = False
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop Until condition1 = False Or i = 17


condition2 = False
i = 4
Do

        If Len(Range("C" & i).Text) > 10 And Len(Range("C" & i).Text) < 13 Then
                condition2 = True

                    If condition1 = True And i = 16 Then
                        Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number length is " & Len(Range("C" & i).Text) & " and is OK ."
                        Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    End If

        Else
            Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number Length not OK. Please check."
            Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbYellow
            condition2 = False

        End If

    i = i + 1
Loop Until condition2 = False Or i = 17



If InStr(1, celltext1, "mz_013_reg-life_") = 1 Then
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The Header is OK."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The header is not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If


If Len(celltext2) > 13 And Len(celltext2) < 15 Then
 Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestamp length is " & Len(celltext2) & " and is OK ."
 Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestanmp not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
Sub Validate13()
Dim mymsg As String
Dim celltext As String
Dim celltext1 As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim checkRng As Range
Dim int1 As Integer
Dim int2 As Integer
Dim int3 As Integer

celltext1 = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Text

Set checkRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4", ActiveSheet.Range("C4").End(xlDown))
If checkRng.Rows.Count > 13 Then
    Set checkRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C16")
End If

If InStr(1, celltext1, "mz_013_reg-life_") = 1 Then
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The Header is OK."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
 Range("$B$26").Value = "The header is not OK. Please check."
 Range("$A$26").Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If


For Each cl In checkRng


    If Not Left(cl.Value, 2) = "44" Then
        int1 = int1 + 1
    End If

    If Len(cl.Value) < 10 Or Len(cl.Value) > 13 Then
        int2 = int2 + 1
    End If

    If Len(cl.Offset(0, 2).Value) < 13 Or Len(cl.Offset(0, 2).Value) > 15 Then
        int3 = int3 + 1
    End If

Next cl

If int1 > 0 Then
    Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number is not OK. Please check."
    Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbYellow
Else
     Range("$B$27").Value = "The subscriber number starts with 44 and is OK."
     Range("$A$27").Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
If int2 > 0 Then
    Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number Length not OK. Please check."
    Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbYellow
Else
    Range("$B$28").Value = "The subscriber number length is OK."
    Range("$A$28").Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
If int3 > 0 Then
   Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestanmp not OK. Please check."
   Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbYellow
Else
   Range("$B$29").Value = "The timestamp length is OK."
   Range("$A$29").Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
End Sub
```

Only problem is you won't know which cell is the sinner if it shows not okay, but I'll guess you can find a work around that.